# C++ error expected ";" before 'endl' how to fix it?

Tags: c++

Im just started studing c++ and im just learned how for , while , if works and im creating very simple decision game based in console and i have problems with endl; line bc its saying expected ';' before 'endl' and i have problem with it . oh and if someone is wondering what language im using in "" its polish

I tried everything i can ;_;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>

string wybor;

int main()
{
   cout << "budzisz sie w totalej ciemnosci ale zauwazasz w oddali dom"endl;
   cout << "A. idz do domu"endl; cout << "B.Podskocz w miejscu"endl;
    cin >> wybor;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cout << "..." ` ** `<<` ** `endl`

Comment: You missed `<<` between `...w oddali dom"` and `endl;`. The next problem you're going to see is `cout: undeclared identifier`, because it's `std::cout`, not just `cout`. Same with `endl` and `cin`;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a `<<` before your `endl`. It should look like this:

```cpp
std::cout << "budzisz sie w totalej ciemnosci ale zauwazasz w oddali dom" << std::endl;
```